# Manifolds with volume forms on every submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, volume, geometric-measure-theory, information-geometry

If we equip a manifold with an inner product (i.e. we have a Riemannian Manifold) then we get a canonical volume form on that manifold (please mentally insert the prefix "pseudo" into my question whenever you feel it necessary).

Whenever we have a submanifold we can pull back the metric along the inclusion map to get an inner product on the submanifold. We then get a volume form on the submanifold.

I'm wondering if there are any converse results to this. I'm looking for some result of the form:

> Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a manifold with a volume form assigned to every submanifold, such that these volume forms satisfy (some consistency condition). Then $\mathcal{M}$ is Riemannian, and the volume forms arise as above.

My only progress so far is to notice that you can define some kind of "norm" on such an $\mathcal{M}$ by, for any vector $v$, picking a curve $\gamma:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ with $\gamma'(0)=v$, letting $\mu$ be the measure on the submanifold which is the image of this curve and then defining
$$\lVert v \rVert=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{\mu(\gamma((0,\varepsilon))}{\varepsilon}.$$
But I don't see what properties I need to put on the volume forms in order to get the triangle inequality or the parallelogram law.

Comment: Ideas: 1. The manifold structure in the question is unnecessary, I could have just asked about a single vector space.

2. Vector spaces with norms already have [two canonical volume forms on every subspace.](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~svivanov/papers/finvol.pdf)

3. If $W\hookrightarrow V$ then it's hard to compare the volume forms on them because the volume form on $V$ vanishes when you pull it back to $W$. But since the volume form on $W$ lives in the 1-dim space $\Lambda^{\mathop{dim}W}W^*$ we can consider its *reciprocal* in $\Lambda^{\mathop{dim}W}W$ and push this forward to $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, we need consider only the tangent space $T_p\mathcal{M}$ at each point $p$ of the manifold $\mathcal{M}$ independently (for this, credit to Oscar Cunningham for this comment on 31 March 2015); every submanifold $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ that contains $p$ has a tangent space $T_p\mathcal{S}$ that is a subspace of $T_p\mathcal{M}$.  Further, by your hypothesis, there is a quadratic form (or, equivalently, a symmetric bilinear form) on the tangent space.  (I assume characteristic $0$ for simplicity.)

For every restriction of the tangent space $T_p\mathcal{M}$ to a $1$-dimensional subspace $\mathcal{S}$, the quadratic form determines (up to a sign) a $1$-form (the volume form for $T_p\mathcal{S}$), ***and vice versa*** (again for $T_p\mathcal{S}$).  The entire quadratic form on $T_p\mathcal{M}$ is then determined up to a single overall sign (this should be evident through continuity across $1$-dimensional subspaces, but does not need continuity to prove).  Through continuity on $\mathcal{M}$, we can extend this to a single selection of sign of the quadratic form for each connected component of the manifold.

Thus, it is clear that the volume forms on the one-dimensional submanifolds are sufficient to determine the quadratic form up to a sign, and hence also the pseudo-Riemannian metric, with the sign being free to choose separately on each connected component of the manifold.  Intuitively, a suitable consistency condition (aside from the usual continuity requirements) is that whenever two submanifolds are contained in a third submanifold and intersect at only one point, the exterior product relates their volume forms at that point.

Comment: Can manifolds be defined over fields other than $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ (which have characteristic $0$)?

Comment: I'm no expert in this, but they can evidently be defined over any fields (and even division rings) of characteristic 0, possibly over other continuous rings.  Going to finite nonzero characteristic, at least a few special cases seem to be possible, such as the $n$-dimensional projective space over a finite field, where conic sections have sensible tangents, which seems to allow for many similarities.  Much of the theory would extend to this context.  As usual, characteristic 2 has some oddities.